# get ID from dataTable with Dataset

Tags: vb.net, oracle, dataset

i'm using visual studio(VB) and i had a problem,

i am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to read the data from excel,

```
--Students_Table--
id_S | Name | Sex
12      john   M

---Excel file------
name | address
john   NY
```

-----the table where uploaded excel file saved--

```
id_u | id-S | Scor |
1      12        30
```

i want to get the Id_S from "John"(excel file), i tried using the dataset with query

```
select Id_P from Students_Table where (Name =: Name)
```

and then check `fillBy` & `GetBy`

my vb code :

```
Dim ta As New Students_TableAdapters.StudentsTableAdapter
Dim DataID as Integer
if ta.fillBy(ExlRead.Value) <> 0 then
DataId = ta.fillBy(ExlRead.Value)
else 
exception("The Name Cannot Found on Database")
end if
```

i use breakpoint to check those and i found an error message

> "ORA-01722: invalid number"

(i'm using oracle database)

if i pointed my cursor to the `ta.fillBy` it shows `Public Overridalle Overload Function FillBy(Name as string) as decimal`?

note :
I'am a newbie
using Oracle Database

Comment: thank's @arion for correcting view

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
ta.fillBy(ExlRead.Value)
```

by

```
CInt(ta.fillBy(CInt(ExlRead.Value)))
```